# What is the meaning of "Sie ist es immer noch"?

Tags: meaning

I read the following sentence:

> Sie ist Flugbegleiterin geworden. Ich glaube, **sie ist es immer noch**.

I don't know if I understand it the right way, but I would think it means that "She's always wanted to be a flight attendant".

Is that correct?

Comment: If you expanded a bit on how you would arrive at that (wrong) conclusion, this question might become on-topic.

Comment: since i could't conclude the meaning of the scentence as a whole, I translated it literally, so it seemed like: She is that always (still). so i ignored (still) and untderstood it that way

Comment: Ignore "immer" and try it again. I'm pretty sure, you'll then end up with the correct conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

> She became a flight attendant. I believe, **she still is one**. (Still works as a flight attendant)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not correct.

The first sentence does not mean "She's always wanted to be a flight attendant". The correct meaning is: "She became a flight attendant".

Here are the correct translation pairs:

1. > Sie ist Flugbegleiterin geworden.
   > She became a flight attendant.
2. > Sie wollte immer eine Flugbegleiterin sein.
   > She always wanted to be a flight attendant.

(I think you variation beginning with "She's" instead of "She" is even wrong in english.)

Number 1 means, that there was a time when she was not a flight attendant (like nobody else she was not born as a flight attendant). And then there was an event that changed this status, and after this event she was a flight attendant. But this sentence does not tell, if there later was another event, that turned back this status. It is not absolutely clear, if she now still is a flight attendant, or if she quit this job.

Number 2 means, that she "always" (from the day of her birth until now) had a certain goal, and this goal was to be a flight attendant. But you don't know if she reached this goal. It is possible, that until now she never became a flight attendant, and still has this dream. But it can also be, that she now is a flight attendant, and is very happy with her job, so now she still wants to be what she is.

---

This is the translation of the second sentence:

> Ich glaube, sie ist es immer noch.
> I believe, she still is.

So the complete translation is this:

> She became a flight attendant. I believe, she still is.